# miktex download failure

Tags: miktex

I was not able to download miktex on my  windows computer.  I was given this error message:

```
An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
  source line: 166
  message: The executed process did not succeed.
  info: fileName="C:\Users\Hector\Documents\Miktex\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="-1073741701"
```

What can I do to download miktex?  Better yet, what does the error mean?

Comment: Download it from here: https://miktex.org/download and make sure that the file is not corrupted before install.

Comment: I tried downloading at this website: https://miktex.org/download   It did not work.  I get the same error: An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
  source line: 166
  message: The executed process did not succeed.
  info: fileName="C:\Users\Hector\Documents\Miktex\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="-1073741701"   I am using trying to download this file:basic-miktex-2.9.6615-x64.exe
Is there something wrong with this file?  Should it be updated to fix this error?

Comment: Doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong. So, I suggest that instead of the installer you are using, get the "portable" version of MikTeX, and install to where you are already trying to install. First remove any partial installation. Why I say this: MikTeX installation errors appear from time to time, but it seems that the portable version is less likely to cause an error.

Comment: i was trying to download miktex but its showing failure. any way to download please suggest

Answer (score -1):

You can download the needed installers listed from below link from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex).
This link provides source, installers and portable setup also.

Comment: Better show a link to the homepage of MiKTeX because there you will find the current version of MiKTeX, the version on ctan is from Mai 2019 only ... Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks @Mensch .. I tried using the homepage of MikTex only.. it failed while downloading in between.. And I checked the version available on CTAN, it has latest versions i.e. https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x64 You just have to manually browse the directories as per your OS distribution requirements